# How to run three.js examples locally in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to run the `three.js` examples locally in a web browser with MacOS. I cloned the whole `three.js` repository and tried to open a file in a browser (e.g. `three.js/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html`), but I get error messages in the console:

```
Access to script at 'file:///Users/me/three.js/build/three.module.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

I searched for a way to run examples in a browser and found something [HERE](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally), but also without success. I navigates to the `example` folder and started a python server. Opening the server address in the browser showed me the list of examples, but clicking on them does not do anything. I get errors like these in the console:

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/files/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (File not found)
```

What am I missing in order to run the examples locally in a browser?

Answer (score 3):

Run the server from the root of the repository instead of from within the examples directory and navigate to the examples directory.  This will allow the urls to resolve properly.

Comment: Ah thanks, that works. I will try to change this important information in the documentation.